# How to SUM specific rows in matrix on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following matrix (example):

[image]

The matrix SUM all rows, but I need a way to say what "Description" I want to SUM, like de following matrix (example):

[image]

I have the following fields on matrix:

**Lines:**

- **Field 1:** Type
- **Field 2:** Description

**Columns:**

- **Field 1:** Month/Year

**Values:**

- **Field 1:** Measure: `CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Values]); Table[LastOfMonth] = "True")`

And for help, I have a column indicator on table (`Table[NeedSum] = "True"`)  saying if that row should SUM on matrix or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Maesure :=
IF (
    HASONEFILTER ( 'Table'[Description] ) = TRUE ();
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Values] ); 'Table'[LastOfMonth] = "True" );
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Values] ); 'Table'[LastOfMonth] = "True";
         'Table'[NeedSum] = "true"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks man, finally I found a way to get the Total row right!